# Doubling Numpy array into bigger array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Is there a way without creating a 2nd variable storing array [1,2,3] and then concatenating
to get [1,2,3,1,2,3] from array1 = [1,2,3].
Could I use numpy.repeat for this?
Input:
[2,3,4]
Output:
[2,3,4,2,3,4]

Comment: np.concatenate((array1, array1))` makes the larger array without a temporary copy of `array1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
>>> np.tile([1,2,3], 2)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```